# What is meant by multiplication in physics such as $s = v·t$?

Tags: kinematics, definition, dimensional-analysis

What is the meaning behind multiplication in physics? Is multiplication in physics purely mathematical or there is a physical explanation to it? How do we explain the product for example, $s = v·t $? Is there any meaning behind this? For example, I can say that "Distance is defined as the product of velocity 'times' time"? But what does this even mean?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Note that the nomenclature $s = v . t$ looks like a dot product, which is different than multiplication.  The correct way to write this equation is $s=vt$, where people who know physics recognize that "v" is velocity and "t" is time (in other words, physics has a standard nomenclature).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many, albeit far from all, "multiplications" in physics are simplified versions of integrals. For example, in your case, saying $\Delta s = v \Delta t$ comes from the definition of velocity 
$$ \vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{s}}{dt} $$
for which we can easily see this has come from an integral:
$$ \vec{s} - \vec{s}_0 = \int_{t_0}^t \vec{v}(t)dt. $$
This equation -- as well as $\Delta s = v\Delta t$ -- tell you that the change in position of an object from $\vec s_0$ to $\vec s$ is the result of a velocity $\vec{v}$ that occurs over time period $t-t_0$. During that time period, the velocity $\vec v$ uses every infintesimal moment $dt$ to change the position by a tiny amount $d\vec s$, until all the little $d\vec s$'s have accumulated up to $\vec{s}-\vec{s}_0$.

There are numerous other places where this occurs: $F = -\frac{dU}{dx}$, $I = \frac{dq}{dt}$, $\Delta V = - \frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$, $P = - \frac{dU}{dV}$, and *many* more.

Another example is Newton's second law -- $F=ma$. If only conservative forces act on your object then you can see it is equivalent to
$$ \frac{dU}{dx} = -m\frac{dv}{dt}.$$
That is to say -- the changes in potential energy over displacement (force) cause the velocity to change over time in proportion to mass.

In the context of vectors, scalar and vector multiplication also contribute the important directions of products, e.g. in Maxwell's equations we have

$$ \nabla \cdot E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$
and 
$$ \nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0\left[\vec{J}+\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t}\right]$$

The first tells you that electric field *diverges* from a source in a way consistent to the distribution of source charge. The second tells you that the magnetic fields produced from real or displacement currents *curl* around the source and form a new vector.

All multiplication in physics has physical meaning. Often this can be found by looking at the underlying definitions of the quantities. After all, the fundamental equations in physics -- Newton's 2nd law, the Schrodinger equation, Maxwell's equations, and so forth -- are each differential equations that link the interactions and energy of/between objects to their motion through spacetime using multiplication.

Comment: Can you provide an image/ a figure in my case ?

Comment: See https://faculty.utrgv.edu/emmett.tomai/courses/3370/mod1/refs/img/euler-auc.png

Comment: Just one more plz

Comment: In the figure of krishna's answer, why does v + v + v + v + v............t does not make any sense

Comment: Thanks I finally understood

Comment: An example of a multiplification that is *not* a simplified version of an integral is $E=\hbar\omega$.

Comment: This is one of those answers that *sounds* good, but that I'm actually somewhat skeptical is fundamentally correct. Specifically this claim: "All multiplication in physics has physical meaning". It's hard for me to see how you can justify this statement without it just becoming tautological - i.e. it has physical meaning because it appears in a physics equation.

Comment: @aquirdturtle fair, but I would say that all physics equations have physical meaning because they are mathematical models build to explain the behavior we observe or predict in reality. It’s not tautological because the equations are models, the meaning is experimental. Probably worth moving this to chat for more discussion.

Answer (score 10):

Basically the multiplication in physics is the same as in mathematics.

But there is one more important thing you need to keep in mind.
Unlike in mathematics, in physical formulas the values have a number *and a unit*.
Therefore, when multiplying two physical values,
then you need not only to multiply their numbers.
You also need to multiply their units.

Let's take for example a car  driving with speed $v = 50 \text{ miles/hour}$,
during a time $t = 2 \text{ hours}$.

Then you can calculate the distance driven by the car by
$$s = v \cdot t$$

Using the values from above and doing the multiplication you get
$$\begin{align}
s &= v \cdot t \\
  &= 50 \text{ miles/hour} \cdot 2 \text{ hours} \\
  &= (50 \cdot 2)\ (\text{miles/hour} \cdot \text{hours}) \\
  &= 100 \text{ miles}  
\end{align}$$

Comment: can u provide a figure/ image

Comment: @OmerFarooq The image would exactly look like the image in Krishna's answer, just only with different numbers.

Comment: then why does v + v + v + v + v............t does not make sense

Comment: @OmerFarooq I guess you first need to understand multiplication of real numbers, which is an extension of integer multiplication, i.e. not just repeated addition/counting.

Comment: @OmerFarooq v = s/t. So v + v = (s/t) + (s/t) = (2s/t) = 2v. Thus (v + v) * t = ((s/t) + (s/t))*t = (2s/t) * t = 2s. It all works out correctly, even if doing pure maths.

Answer (score 4):

Physics can be thought of as the subset of mathematics which happens to make correct predictions about the Real World (tm) [at least roughly speaking]. As such in my view it's probably a mistake to read too much into the "physical meaning of multiplication" beyond the mathematical definitions.

Of course there are lots of friendly-sounding examples to give people of intuition about multiplication - e.g. counting groups of something. $4\times5$ can be thought of as 4 groups of 5 things each, and this remains true for most physical quantities in some sense. However, the math doesn't care about this interpretation of the expression - the math stands by itself. So it's perfectly reasonable and self-consistent to drop the fluff and focus on the cold-hard math.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest way multiplication can be understood in linear relations such as in your example is: “is proportional to with this coefficient.”

Distance is proportional to time. The coefficient of proportionality is called “velocity.”

Comment: This is very misleading and fails even in very simple cases. Displacement is the integral of velocity over time, and there is no 'proportionality'. The mass of a solid homogenous sphere is **not** proportional to its radius $r$, but to the cube of its radius, and there is no meaningful sense in which what you said can be used to understand the product $r·r·r$.

Comment: @user21820 I disagree. You appear to have a narrow conception of proportionality. “Displacement = Rate * Time” is *exactly* a statement of proportionality. If you wanted a more nuanced expression, capturing the possibility that velocity might not be constant, then you would have used a different formula.

Comment: You fail to acknowledge your explanation's failure in anything beyond linear relations. I wonder whose conception is narrow...

Comment: @user21820 Read OP’s question again. Think about where he/she is asking the question from. Do you really think that my answer is unhelpful? If you wish to improve it, you have the power.

Comment: I read the question carefully, and I think there are many much better answers than yours that have already been posted (which I upvoted). The bottom line is that your answer is based on too narrow conceptualizations of multiplication in physics. So there is no point for me to attempt to improve it. If I were to give an answer, it would be roughly along the lines of aquirdturtle's, though zhutchens1's answer addresses the fact that many instances of multiplication are just special cases of the actual physically meaningful integrals. Or perhaps, more accurately, $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: If it helps you understand where I am coming from, I view this question as one that ought to be answered by a connection between mathematical multiplication and its appearance in physics-related phenomena that has both explanatory power and predictive power. If you have basic knowledge of first-order logic, this corresponds to the fact that a theory about a first-order structure is not only satisfied by the assumptions we have about the structure (i.e. explains the observations we had made previously) but also proves new facts about the structure (i.e. predicts future observations).

Comment: Please understand that I have nothing against you personally, but I do frankly think that your answer is simply wrong (I didn't want to say "wrong" in my first comment but that's truly what I think). The reason is that all the 5 instances of multiplication in the formula for the mass of a homogenous sphere, namely $m = \frac43·π·r·r·r·ρ$ where $ρ$ is its density, are **exactly the same**. Since your answer's claim about proportionality fails here, it is impossible to be a correct explanation of multiplication in physics.

Comment: @user21820 Thank you for your explanation. You will only consider an answer correct if it succeeds rigorously in every case. (I wouldn’t want to call that position “pedantic,” but thats truly what I think.) I have a different goal with my answers, which is to provide a helpful intuition, if that’s what I think the OP desires. I believe that the concept of proportionality (as represented by multiplication) is remarkably useful in physics and absolutely aproopos to the question. Neglecting to mention it somewhere in these answers would run counter to the spirit of Physics.SE.

Comment: @user21820 Nevertheless, I have narrowed the scope of my answer as per your suggestion. Hopefully this satisfies your sensibilities?

Comment: Thank you for narrowing the scope of your answer. I have no problems with it now and removed my downvote. And I have no issue with you calling me pedantic; I'm pedantic only because I've seen too many conceptual errors by students who were not taught to carefully understand the scope of what they are told. Anyway all the best! =)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of thinking about this intuitively is to first understand the meaning of speed. If a car has a speed of 60 miles per hour, this means that every hour the car traverses 60 miles. So, if 2 hours have elapsed, the car traverses 120 miles which is 60*2. Abstracting this now to variables, if a car is moving with a speed $v$, and a time $t$ has elapsed, the distance the car traverses is $v*t$.

This is precisely the same interpretation multiplication has in mathematics. If your teacher hands 3 cookies per student, and they have 30 students, how many cookies do they have to hand out? It's 30*3=90.

Answer (score 1):

Distance covered = velocity × time

is saying that "fastness of the object" multiplied by ``time taken'' gives the total distance covered (for linear and uniform velocities only).

The ``Physical interpretation of multiplication'' comes from the units involved. Without the physical units all operations are just pure mathematics.

To find a physical meaning in the mathematical operations like product,addition,subtraction and division would change from context to context in physics.

Answer (score -2):

Multiplication in physics does have meaning. For instance take the very example you gave, "what is distance?"

We know that velocity is the distance travelled in one unit time, say like one second. Now, if you travel for 10 seconds, you are essentially travelling the distance travelled in 1 second ten times.

If numbers fit better, consider this situation. Let us assume that you can walk 5m in one minute. In 10 minutes you would have walked 50 metres, very obviously. So, here you are travelling 'time' times the 'velocity' i.e. '10 time' times the distance travelled in 'one time'.

Notice that the factor of time cancels out and you are left with 10 times (not 'time') the distance, which is what we want.

See the image below

[image]

We can break the 5 seconds into 5 interval s of 1 second, and in each second, the body travels a distance equal to the velocity (by the definition of velocity), and added the distances.

Comment: Then why does v + v + v + v + v............t does not make sense

Comment: I think the diagram is quite confusing, definitely to OP and to me as well. It says $x=v$, and that $s=vt=5x$. That is inconsistent -- $s\neq5v$ dimensionally.

Comment: I am confused now to believe you or @zhutchens1

Comment: FINALLY after 5hrs I have understood completely. Thanks

Comment: I understand that there is something inherently wrong with this post, but I cannot realize where I'm wrong. Can someone please tell me where I'm wrong? (I don't mind the down votes, but I might have given the OP a wrong answer)

Comment: You have given me the correct answer. I had already up voted you.

Comment: @OmerFarooq, I know, I was not saying that you down voted me. But if three people feel my answer is not good, there might be a problem with my answer (sometimes in the language used, like lacks clarity etc.). That's all. Knowing them helps me post better answers. (Many people are kind enough to help me in doing so.)

Comment: Nothing seems wrong here. In fact it is one of top 2 answers. Maybe we just can't provide perfect answers because they can't understand our wording. Hope you get it.

Comment: @OmerFarooq Thanks :-). Once, one of my answer was downvoted, and after a kind user told me to improve my wording it got a good number of upvotes. Answers here are for people to understand, right? No need to worry much about this.